# Customize p:tab titles in p:accordionPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to add some component in the accordion panel **tab itself**, not the cascading panel as shown below.

[image]

I would like to add a commandButton or a progress bar as 'quick' summary of data or functionality of what is actually contained in the 'hidden' panel.

Is this possible? or do i have to teach myself how to write a custom component? sample code below.

Am not expert and am literally stuck here.

```html
<p:accordionPanel>
  <p:tab title="Tab 0">
    <f:facet name="face0">
      <p:outputLabel value="hello 0"></p:outputLabel>
    </f:facet>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab title="Tab 1">
    <f:facet name="facet1">
      <p:outputLabel value="hello 1"></p:outputLabel>
    </f:facet>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab title="Tab 2">
    <f:facet name="facet2">
      <p:outputLabel value="hello 2"></p:outputLabel>
    </f:facet>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab title="Tab 3">
    <p:outputLabel value="hello hidden panel"></p:outputLabel>
  </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: oh! What is the correct component to output plain text?

Comment: Just use EL. See also https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/performance?id=patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`p:accordion` documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/accordionpanel?id=getting-started-with-accordion-panel)

> Titles can also be defined with `title` facet.

So you can do:

```html
<p:accordionPanel>  
    <p:tab>
        <f:facet name="title">
            Your components
        </f:facet>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: ..seem still to be an issue. I edited the question and run a new piece of xhtm based on your suggestion...the outputLabels are not visible? Many Thanks. Looking at JSF core now..

Comment: Your code is wrong.. don't use `f:facet name="whatever"`, use `f:facet name="title"`

Comment: Works well! Thanks